# Flag got declined

Tags: discussion

I recently flaged a post I believe was off topic:

[Convert nginx rewrite rule to htaccess rewrite rule](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211722/convert-nginx-rewrite-rule-to-htaccess-rewrite-rule)

And the flag was declined. Is this correct decision? Should this question not be asked on different community such as **Server Fault**?

This question is still not answered and I believe if it was asked in correct place, it would be answered already.

**Can you tell me why you think this question belongs on Magento SE?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag was automatically declined by the system because in the review queue it got 3 "Leave open" votes: https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/close/130863.
Indeed, this looks like it is not really about Magento, but this can be just our opinion.

Comment: The reason for my flag was because I believe the person who asked the question would get better answer in different community. The question was asked Jan 31 and still didn't receive an answer, do you think it's worth moving the question to different community or leaving it here?

Comment: The question is too old to migrate.

Comment: Answered my question. Thanks Marius.